# Exception record for hangs

Tags: windbg

Whenever we analyze a hang dump, if we try .exr -1,

The following result is seen.

ExceptionAddress: 000000
ExceptionCode: cfffffff (Application Hang)

.exr -1 means "last exception thrown".

Who is throwing the exception when the application is hung. Normally, in case of crashes, system throws an exception and KiUserDispatch... catches it and proceeds.

But what happens when a hang occurs? Is system throwing an exception? From where that exception record comes from?

Comment: Interesting. How did you generate the dump?

Comment: Just by using .dump /ma X.dmp ...mini dump... Wondering where that exception record came from?

Comment: The question is really how the dump was generated. My guess is that it's generated by WER (windows error reporting) which kicks in if you're trying to send an UI event to an responsive thread, in which case you can choose terminating the unresponsive app and a crash dump that results will have this as an exception recorded.

Answer (score 0):

An application hang does not generate any exception, so you must examine the call stack for all threads and try to figure out “who is waiting for who”

The following commands my help you:

a) Examine all stacks

```
~*e ?? @$tid;kvn
```

b) List critical section locked with the owners stack

```
!cs –l -o
```

Also you could try DebugDiag to do a Crash/Hang analyze

Comment: But the OP shows that `.exr -1` shows "Application Hang" in its output. I wonder how that gets in there.

Comment: @Marc notice the null exception address, this can’t be valid.
I’m not sure, but maybe lack of a valid exception record is interpreted as hang. 
Anybody who knows?

Comment: Thanks Kjell. I am aware of finding out causes. My question was "From where that exception record comes from?" .. What exr -1 does internally?